# Changing the angular.js file with new one manually

Tags: angularjs

I am using a seed project for Angular apps. There is no bower to manage the dependencies. The angular.js file is currently in the below location. Here is the index.html content:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="AngularSpringApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Service App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/app.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">

    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#/cars">Cars</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/trains">Trains</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/railwaystations">Railway Station</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/kits">Kits</a></li>
    </ul>
    <hr class="" />
    <div ng-view></div>

</div>
<script src="resources/js/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/dirPagination.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/services.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/controllers/RailwayStationController.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/controllers/CarController.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/controllers/TrainController.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/controllers/KitController.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/filters.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/directives.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the beginning of the app.js file:

```
var AngularSpringApp = angular.module('AngularSpringApp', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);

// Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
AngularSpringApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when ...
```

As you can see, ngRoute module is not injected, but the the routing is working properly!

Now, I am trying to change the current angular file with new angular.js file which I downloaded from the Angular website. When replacing the angular.js file, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module AngularSpringApp due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvider
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$injector/unpr?p0=%24routeProvider
    at http://localhost:8084/app/resources/js/lib/angular/angular.js:78:12
    at http://localhost:8084/app/resources/js/lib/angular/angular.js:3801:19
    at getService (http://localhost:8084/app/resources/js/lib/angular/angular.js:3929:39)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:8084/app/resources/js/lib/angular/angular.js:3956:13)
    at http://localhost:8084/app/resources/js/lib/angular/angular.js:3884:37
    at forEach (http://localhost:8084/app/resources/js/lib/angular/angular.js:325:18)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:8084/app/resources/js/lib/angular/angular.js:3871:5)
    at createInjector (http://localhost:8084/app/resources/js/lib/angular/angular.js:3811:11)
    at doBootstrap (http://localhost:8084/app/resources/js/lib/angular/angular.js:1444:20)
    at bootstrap (http://localhost:8084/app/resources/js/lib/angular/angular.js:1459:12)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$injector/modulerr?p0=AngularSpringApp&p…ost%3A8084%2Fapp%2Fresources%2Fjs%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A1459%3A12)
```

Comment: You mean to say it does not work? Please edit your body - unable to comprehend your situation. And also please provide more relevant details.Best way to know what is wrong is to open the browser console and look for errors.

Comment: Sorry for the complications, I edited the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely also need to download and include the [angular-route](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) module after your angular.js include:

```
<script src="resources/js/lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
```

Comment: I added the app.js content to the question. Initially, there is no dependency injection for angular-route module in the app.js and it is just working fine! I do not have any explanation for this though!

Comment: OK, now I understand. The angular.js that I had was version v1.0.3 which I think it included the ngRoute at that time. Now it is separated module which needed to be added.